# Shadow price not covering costs

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, economics

In (environmental) econ class we had to solve the following problem:

```
min
costs = clean*2 + 1*dirty (where 2 and 1 are the respective input prices)

s.t.

production: 8 = (clean^0.4)*(dirty^0.6)

climate constraint: clean > 2*dirty
```

Using the Lagrange-multiplier of production as the price for the output good, all costs are exactly covered. However, if I change the climate constaint to:

```
climate constraint: clean > 14 (just to give an example)
```

the costs are not covered anymore if I take the the Lagrange-multiplier as price for the output good. Interestingly, there is also no Problem if I set the climate constraint to:

```
climate constraint: clean > 2 (which is more than would be optimal without the climate constraint)
```

Can anyone explain to me why this price-interpretation of the Lagrange-multiplier sometimes works and sometimes doesn't? Could it be connected to whether the solution is interior or not?

Best and thanks in advance,

F.

Comment: Usually you cannot apply the method of lagrange multiplier if an **in**equality is involved.

Comment: @callculus I used the Kuhn-Tucker Method with the Lagrange equation. That should be fine, right?

Comment: Yes, this method should work.

Comment: @callculus And also the interpretation of the multiplier as price should work, right? But this seems not to be the case in the example above.

Comment: Yes, it should work. But without the climate constraint the optimal solution is clean=4.13825 and dirty=12.4148. So the optimal value for clean is greater than $2$.

Comment: For the optimal value the following equation must hold: $\frac{c^*}{d^*}=\frac{0.4}{0.6}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac13$. This is true, since the optimal value of dirty is three times of the optimal clean value.

Comment: @callculus Maybe I don't get you but with `climate constraint: clean > 2*dirty` I get a multiplier value of 3.7893. If I multiply this by 8, the production, this perfectly covers the production costs of 30.3143. However, if I use `climate constraint: clean > 14`, I get a multiplier of 1.1477 which is not enough to cover the costs of 33.5089. So, I wonder when I can use the multiplier w.r.t. the production constraint as a "price" and when this interpretation is not right.

Comment: I don´t know if you interprete the multiplier correctly. Let´s say you have the optimal values ,for a min problem, $z^*$ and$ \lambda^*$  and a constraint like $b-g(x)$ If you add a small value of $\delta$ to $b$, then the optimal value of the objective function changes approximately to $z_{new}^*\approx z^*+\lambda^*\cdot \delta$

Comment: Sure, but as the above function is homothetic, I thought the price interpretation of the multiplier is fine. At least this has always worked for similar production problems without such "climate"-type constraint.